# Set Apache Spark's BlockManager memory

Tags: memory, apache-spark

My spark cluster running info is

> 15/12/29 17:45:33 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block
>   manager 10.108.98.123:51075 with **530.3 MB RAM**, BlockManagerId(8,
>   10.108.98.123, 51075

How to modify  530.3MB to  20g or 10g?

I have make code that is

```
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.python.worker.memory", "10g").
set('spark.driver.memory', '10g')
```

Still  it takes only `530.3MB RAM` and my setting did not reflect.

Is there a way to set it?

Comment: What's mode you run spark? Client? Cluster?

Comment: If you are running in yarn and in cluster the following command is useful while the spark job in the command line

spark-submit --class "your.path.to.the.class" --master yarn --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 10g --driver-memory 10g --executor-cores 1 theNameofTheJar.jar

Answer (score 1):

The BlockManager is only a component running on each node (driver or worker).
See this source for a bit more details on what it's doing: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-blockmanager.html

It's not directly impacted  by the settings you're manipulating.

I couldn't find how to specifically set the memory it's using though.